# How to use Content Access Module API to Revoke Owner Edit for a Node?

Tags: users, nodes

I have a custom field for a manager to approve a node. When the node status is set to "approved" I need to revoke the owner's permission to edit the node. I am using the [Content Access module](https://drupal.org/project/content_access), but can't figure out which API call will revoke the owner's permission to edit the particular node.

Comment: Over last 2 years number of open bugs is going up steadily and module is hardly maintained...I'm afraid you will not have much luck with it.